# Subroutine being being called, but something wrong with arithmetic?

Tags: assembly, mips, subroutine

I am almost done writing this program in assembly to have the user input two values, (u,v), then calling a subroutine to calculate X * Y * Z.  the formula is

7u^2 - 25uv + 63v^2

where the first X * Y * Z is 7u^2, second is 25uv and so on.

I'm supposed to call the subroutine three times, and I believe everything is called properly but I can't see to figure out why the arithmetic is wrong, for example when I type in u=1 and v=1 the result comes back as -25.  Below is my code, any ideas?

also when I input 0 and 0 to end the program it comes up with result is: 0 for both times I type it in, when I'm trying to end it.

Thanks guys!

EDIT: 
some progress I made along with this program, still can't get it to print out the correct result, only a few numbers away now.

EDIT2:
it may not be pretty, but I just got it to work the way it's supposed to, with much help from a commentor down there, but this code runs and does what it's intended to do.

```
        # $a0 - 7/25/63
        # $a1 - u
        # $a2 - v

        .text
        .globl main

main:

loop:
li $v0, 4 # print string syscall method
la $a0, prompt # prints prompt 
syscall

li $v0, 4 # print string syscall method
la $a0, prompt1 # prints prompt 
syscall

li $v0, 5 # reads the int typed
syscall

#gets u
move $a1, $v0
addu $s0, $a1, 0
beq $a1, $zero, test
nop
test:


li $v0, 4 # print string syscall method
la $a0, prompt2 # prints prompt 
syscall

li $v0, 5 # reads int
syscall

# gets v
move $s1, $v0
beq $s1, $zero, endlp 
nop
addu $s3, $s1, 0
addu $a2, $a1, 0
li $a0, 7 # loads the int 7 into $a0
jal arithmetic # jumps to subroutine
nop # nop

move $a2, $s1 
move $s2, $v1 # where subrouting comes back to, moves the result into $s1

li $a0, -25 # loads -25 into $a0
jal arithmetic
nop

addu $s2, $s2, $v1 # moves result to s2
move $a1, $s3 # puts v in a1
li $a0, 63
jal arithmetic
nop

addu $s2, $s2, $v1

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s2
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall

j loop
nop




        .data
prompt: .asciiz "Type zero for both u and v to end program\n"
prompt1: .asciiz "Please type value for 'u': \n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Please type value for 'v': \n"
prompt3: .asciiz "Result is: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"


        .text
        .globl arithmetic
arithmetic:

mul $a3, $a1, $a2
mul $v1, $a0, $a3
jr $ra
nop


endlp:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: The latest version is still not completely 100% correct (does wrong thing for certain input). :) :P  (subtle, very subtle, special case)

Comment: Ok, so I ran it, and the program ends when I hit 0 for both values, time to go through every integer possible, i'll get back to you in a few billion years

Comment: ok found it, it has to do with ending, basically it ends if v is 0 no matter what u is, hopefully that's what you were talking about and not something else lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 2, containing reviewed the updated source from OP (after he fixed the problems with original source):

Just adjusted source, how I would expect it to be written:

```sh
# register allocation through main code:
# s0 = u, s1 = v, s2 = intermediate/final result

# WARNING: code needs delayed branching ON (like real MIPS CPU)

        .text
        .globl main
main:

    li $v0, 4       # print string syscall method
    la $a0, prompt  # prints prompt 
    syscall

    # input "u"
    li $v0, 4       # print string syscall method
    la $a0, prompt1 # prints "u" prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5       # reads the int typed
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0   # remember "u" input

    # input "v"
    li $v0, 4       # print string syscall method
    la $a0, prompt2 # prints "v" prompt 
    syscall

    li $v0, 5       # reads the int typed
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0   # remember "v" input

    # result = 0
    move $s2, $zero

    # exit when user did enter pair of zeroes
    or   $at, $s0, $s1 # binary OR(u, v)
    bne  $at, $zero, doCalculation  # when both inputs are zero -> terminate
    li   $v0, 10    # nop not needed, v0=10 is harmless in case of calculation
    syscall         # terminate

doCalculation:
    # calculate result += 7*u*u
    move $a1, $s0   # a1 = u
    move $a2, $s0   # a2 = u
    jal arithmetic  # jumps to subroutine
    li   $a0, 7     # load a0 in delayed branching as argument for subroutine
    add  $s2, $s2, $v0   # update result

    # calculate result += -25*u*v
    move $a1, $s0   # a1 = u
    move $a2, $s1   # a2 = v
    jal arithmetic  # jumps to subroutine
    li   $a0, -25   # load a0 in delayed branching as argument for subroutine
    add  $s2, $s2, $v0   # update result

    # calculate result += 63*v*v
    move $a1, $s1   # a1 = v
    move $a2, $s1   # a2 = v
    jal arithmetic  # jumps to subroutine
    li   $a0, 63    # load a0 in delayed branching as argument for subroutine
    add  $s2, $s2, $v0   # update result

    # display result    
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, prompt3
    syscall

    li   $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s2
    syscall

    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, newline
    syscall

    j    main   # rinse and repeat until [0, 0] user input
    nop         # needed, to not execute slow MUL from subroutine

arithmetic:
    mul $v0, $a1, $a2
    jr  $ra
    mul $v0, $a0, $v0  # v0 = a0 * a1 * a2

        .data
prompt:  .asciiz "Type zero for both u and v to end program\n"
prompt1: .asciiz "Please type value for 'u': \n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Please type value for 'v': \n"
prompt3: .asciiz "Result is: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: this is great man, I'm going to use the code I wrote just because I don't want to copy-paste yours, but what you wrote is absolutely more efficent and organized, and I will use this as a study sheet, and practice this as I move along in this course, I can't thank you enough man, and if I have any questions about anything else I'll seek you out, because you helped me exactly the right way, didn't give me the answer, you made me think about it, and after I figured out how to do it, you organized it to a more efficient looking code.  You are clearly a great teacher, thank you again.

Comment: @alwaysquestioning it's not really efficient. It even contains some redundant `move` instructions (ahead of `jal arithmetic`). It's written with focus on clarity, accuracy and maintainability. Although the delay-slot usage for actual instructions is sort of PITA to read, your "always nop after branch" is simpler strategy, and less error prone. That was kind of show-off thing, to give you idea what that delayed branching truly means, and how it works. (also I wanted to practice it myself, as I always just read about it ;) never tried it before)

Comment: @alwaysquestioning  To turn this into "efficient" code I would put the `mul` instructions 6x directly into code (to save on calling subroutine), and reuse registers more aggressively, not having any redundant `move`. But as your code wait for user input at the beginning, and outputs result into console, the tiny inefficiencies like subroutine calls or few `move` instructions are on micro-second levels, while user input is delayed by seconds, so there's no point to push tasks like this for most performant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
beq $a1, $zero, test1 # tests if $a1 is equal to zero, will go to test if it is
```

You test `u` prematurely, when `v` was not yet inputted, but then you jump forward to a place, where `v` is expected to be already in inputted, and it is not. Let the user enter both `u` and `v`, then test for the [0, 0] pair, you can actually do that with single test like:

```
or  $at, $a1, $a2      ; assumes: a1 = u, a2 = v
beq $at, $zero, endlp  ; when (u|v) == 0 end
```

Also you don't store the `v` into `$a2`, but you do some weird things with `t1` and `a2`, ending with copy of `u` in both `a1` and `a2`.

Use your MARS/SPIM simulator environment to single step over instructions, and watch values in registers, and reason about why what happens. Also where your -25 comes from for [1, 1] input.

I don't mind to help with debugging some confusing problem, but testing clearly wrong value in register against zero looks like you don't know how to debug at all, or you didn't spend any effort on it.

How did you manage to miss that premature jump to `test1` skipping input of second value?

---

EDIT: and about arithmetic results.. I think you mix up registers.

That initial comment pinpoint `a0` to constants, `a1` to *u*, and `a2` to *v* sounds good, but why do you then juggle around with them, like you don't have another million of spare `tX` register for intermediate results? Also if you want to return result in `v0`, then you can mostly calculate directly into it all the time, using it also for intermediate results, avoiding modification of function arguments, if you plan to use them later.

I would clean that register usage and rather write that code a bit more in "functional" way, where you set up particular register value just once, like fake "read only", so your arithmetic subroutine would do `v0 = a0 * a1 * a2` (modifying only `v0`), then you can for example sum up total result in `s1` and ... well, I don't see any reason to use more registers (for the calculation itself, after the inputs are done). Streamline it a bit.

---

EDIT2:
About copy of `u` ... and you are right, I forgot about that one... so I suggest one more register usage redesign. In common MIPS calling conventions the `sX` registers are preserved when calling subroutines, so let's do it other way, after inputs put `s0 = u, s1 = v, s2 = reserved for result`, then set up `a0, a1, a2` from those every time, it will at least read well for code reviewer. Sorry for confusion.

i.e.:

```
v0 = arithmetic(a0=7, a1=s0 (u), a2=s0 (u))
s2 = v0   ; reset result to first intermediate
v0 = arithmetic(a0=-25, a1=s0 (u), a2=s1 (v))
s2 += v0  ; add to result
v0 = arithmetic(a0=63, a1=s1 (v), a2=s1 (v))
s2 += v0  ; add to result to have final total
; display s2 as result
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160223/discussion-on-answer-by-ped7g-subroutine-being-being-called-but-something-wrong).